# how can I implement an external trait on an internal trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, thrust, rust-cargo, wasm-bindgen

I want to print the instance of **Tweet** datatype in main function, but the summary trait don't implement the debug trait. Is there any way to implement a trait on trait or any work around.
uncommentating the second line and commentating the first line would work because String type implements the Display trait.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tweet {
    name: String,
}

pub trait Summary {
    fn summarize(&self) -> String;
}

impl Summary for Tweet {
    fn summarize(&self) -> String {
        format!("@{}", &self.name)
    }
}

fn summarizeable(x: String) -> impl Summary {
    Tweet { name: x }
}

fn main() {
    //1.
    println!("{:#?}", summarizeable(String::from("Alex")));
    //2.println!("{}",summarizeable(String::from("Alex")).summarize());
}
```

> error[E0277]: `impl Summary` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`   -->
>   src/main.rs:26:29    | 26 |     /*1.*/
>   println!("{:#?}",summarizeable(String::from("Alex")));    |
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
>   `impl Summary` cannot be
>   formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`  |    = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `impl Summary`    = note: required by `std::fmt::Debug::fmt`
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
>   error: Could not compile `p1`.
>
> To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.

Answer (score 2):

You can require that anything that `impl`s `Summary` must also `impl` `std::fmt::Debug` as follows:

```
pub trait Summary : std::fmt::Debug { // Summary requires Debug
    fn summarize(&self) -> String;
}
```

If you do not want to tie `Debug` to `Summary` you can always introduce another trait subsuming the other two:

```
pub trait DebuggableSummary : Summary + std::fmt::Display {}
```